# Swift, Firebase: How to insert (not append) Array of a model object into a different array

Tags: arrays, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

I have an array of Categories and an array of Sports hobbies inside my Firebase Database. I fetch them both when the view loads and append them seperately into a `categoriesArray = [Hobbies]` & `sportsArray = [Hobbies]`.

My problem is that inside my didSelectItemAtIndexPath method I want to **INSERT and NOT APPEND** all of the sportsArray into the categoriesArray at that indexPath of Sports BUT I either get an error saying that it cannot convert value type of [Hobbies] to expected argument type of Hobbies OR an error saying it wants to insert an array of Strings instead. How do I get around this? Thank you guys... Means a lot.

My Database:

[image: 1]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class Hobbies: NSObject {

    var hobbieName: String?
}

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CategoriesView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var categoriesArray = [Hobbies]()
    var sportsArray = [Hobbies]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Hashtag"

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)

        handleFetchCategories()
        handleFetchSports()
    }

    func handleFetchCategories() {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("categories")

        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let hobbieNames = snapshot.value as? String {

                let hobbie = Hobbies()

                hobbie.hobbieName = hobbieNames

                self.categoriesArray.append(hobbie)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    func handleFetchSports() {

        let sportsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("sports")

        sportsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let sportsNames = snapshot.value as? String {

                let hobbie = Hobbies()

                hobbie.hobbieName = sportsNames

                self.sportsArray.append(hobbie)
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    func insertElementAtIndexPath(element: [String], index: Int) {
        categoriesArray.insert(contentsOf: element, at: index)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.item == 1 {
            insertElementAtIndexPath(element: sportsArray, index: indexPath.item + 1)

            self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates(
                {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0) as IndexSet)
            }, completion: { (finished:Bool) -> Void in

            })
        }

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categoriesArray.count
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

You try to insert an array of `Strings` to your array of `Hobbies` here

```
func insertElementAtIndexPath(element: [String], index: Int) {
    categoriesArray.insert(contentsOf: element, at: index)
}
```

### Solution

Just change the type of your array in the parameter of `insertElementAtIndexPath(element:index:)` to `Hobbies`

```
func insertElementAtIndexPath(element: [Hobbies], index: Int) {
    categoriesArray.insert(contentsOf: element, at: index)
}
```